# Can I specify ordinal for enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

The `ordinal()` method returns the ordinal of an enum instance.
How can I set the ordinal for an enum?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can't set it. It is always the ordinal of the constant definition. See the [documentation for Enum.ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29):

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.

And actually - you should not need to. If you want some integer property, define one.

Comment: If I can specify the ordinal of enum, when use JPA with enum, that will be more safe...

Answer (score 90):

You can control the ordinal by changing the order of the enum, but you cannot set it explicitly like in `C++`.  One workaround is to provide an extra method in your enum for the number you want:

```
enum Foo {
  BAR(3),
  BAZ(5);
  private final int val;
  private Foo(int v) { val = v; }
  public int getVal() { return val; }
}
```

In this situation `BAR.ordinal() == 0`, but `BAR.getVal() == 3`.

Comment: +1 except this isn't a workaround, really.  it's desired behavior.  the ordinal value is considered an implementation artifact; if you want to assign an integer or other value, that's what "enums are clases" is so great...

Comment: wouldnt BAR.ordinal() return 0 afaik enum indexes are zero based

Answer (score 10):

As the accepted answer points out, you can't set the ordinal. The closest you can get to this is with **a custom property**:

```
public enum MonthEnum {

    JANUARY(1),
    FEBRUARY(2),
    MARCH(3),
    APRIL(4),
    MAY(5),
    JUNE(6),
    JULY(7),
    AUGUST(8),
    SEPTEMBER(9),
    OCTOBER(10),
    NOVEMBER(11),
    DECEMBER(12);

    MonthEnum(int monthOfYear) {
        this.monthOfYear = monthOfYear;
    }

    private int monthOfYear;

    public int asMonthOfYear() {
        return monthOfYear;
    }

}
```

*Note*: By default, `enum` values start at `0` (not `1`) if you don't specify values. Also, the values do not have to increment by `1` for each item.

Answer (score 5):

You can update ordinal using reflection:

```
private void setEnumOrdinal(Enum object, int ordinal) {
    Field field;
    try {
        field = object.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("ordinal");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(object, ordinal);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't update enum ordinal: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're willing to do this, you might as well reorder the enum fields. It's easier, safer and more readable.

Comment: @Gili I agree with you.  But, reordering the enum fields wouldn't allow for non-contiguous ordinals.  Whereas this technique would. (not that I'd ever go to this extreme myself)

Answer (score 2):

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

> public final int ordinal()Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.
>
> Returns:
>   the ordinal of this enumeration constant

If you have

> public enum Day {
>       SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
>       THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
>   }

then SUNDAY has an ordinal of 0, MONDAY is 1, and so on...

Comment: ortinal is not guaranteed to give the ordering above!

Comment: @claj, can you expand on that a bit? The documentation seems to indicate it does.

Comment: Sorry @Celos, the first enum is indeed 0, but the spec does not mention how the value should be assigned at all apart from being monotonically increasing. I think I read something about this caveat in Effective Java or so, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Java [Enum examples](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) and [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29)

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.

Answer (score -6):

The easy answer: just change the order of the constants.  The first defined will be 0, the second will be 1, etc.  However, this may not be practical if you have constantly changing code, or enums will many many values.  You can define a custom method to work around the default ordinal, but MAKE SURE it is well documented to avoid confusion!

```
public enum Values
{
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR;

    public int getCustomOrdinal()
    {
        if(this == ONE)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else if(this == TWO)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: A switch statement might be better than a series of if-else statements.

Comment: I dislike this solution. Enums are classes and therefore can contain custom properties. I'd rather properly define a field for this and a corresponding getter method.

Comment: That is the better solution in general.  But the question asked if it's possible to change the behavior of ordinal()...

Comment: why not just declare a property "customOrdinal" and then you'd initialize your enum constants as `ONE(3)` , `TWO(0)` etc. to get rid of any if/else or switch statements?