# Does Java support Non-Incrementing Values for Enums?

Tags: java, enums

I have a class that defines a `Map<Integer, String> commands` variable, wherein the Integer is the command number and the String is the name for it.

The reason I didn't make this an `enum` is that I was under the impression that values in an `enum` have to be sequential, *id est* increment by one (but the command keys don't). Having looked at the below code, I'm of the impression that this assumption of mine is wrong:

```
public enum HttpStatusCode {
 OK(200), NO_CONTENT(204), NOT_FOUND(404) /* .... */ ;
}
```

Do the values in an enum have to increment by one for each value or are gaps in value allowed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372855/can-i-specify-ordinal-for-enum-in-java maybe this will help also

Comment: If you've already got a map, you could also just use the enum as the key and forget about values completely.

Comment: @KacperWolkowski Thanks. I had looked at that example/answer prior to posting. However, it shows the values being set in sequence. (It also starts at `1`, which led me to believe that the first ordinal in an enum is `1`, not `0`.)

Comment: In Java, enums are fully functional classes, you can give them as many fields as you want to (as seen in the answer from @daniu). In general you shouldn't care about or use the value of `ordinal()` for anything.

Comment: s/functional/functioning/g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaps are allowed, in fact you can define an actual constructor.

```
public enum HttpStatusCode {
   OK(200), NO_CONTENT(204), NOT_FOUND(404);
   private int status;
   private HttpStatusCode(int st) { status = st; }
   public int getStatus() { return status; }       
}
```

You still get incremental values by the `ordinal()`.